# Datetime2 in liquibase

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

What is the correct data type for creating a column with datetime2 in mssql using liquibase? I tried using timestamp, datetime and datetime2 but they all mapped to datetime. I need the extra precision that datetime2 gives.
According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27925331/4837366), it could map to either, is there a way that I could force it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's just specifying "datetime2" as the type as shown below:

```
<column name="UTC_Updated_At" type="datetime2" defaultValueComputed="SYSDATETIME()">
```